# Render only unique labels in React Native Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON which can be also accessed through http://myjson.com/kfd04

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "customer": "Star Wars",
      "project": "1977"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "customer": "Star Wars",
      "project": "1985"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "customer": "The Matrix",
      "project": "1999"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "customer": "Inception",
      "project": "2010"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "customer": "Interstellar",
      "project": "2014"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to only render the unique customers this is my code so far. It displays all the customers. The `responseData` contains the "response" array of objects.

```
<Picker
  mode="dialog"
  selectedValue={this.state.customerName}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    this.setState({ customerName: itemValue });
    }
  }
  >
    {
      this.state.responseData.map((item) => (
      <Picker.Item label={item.customer} value={item.customer} key={item.customer} />))
    }
</Picker>
```

Comment: Try filtering out the values before rendering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reduce your array to filter out unique values, for this you can make use of reduce method

```js
const data = {
  "response": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "customer": "Star Wars",
      "project": "1977"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "customer": "Star Wars",
      "project": "1985"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "customer": "The Matrix",
      "project": "1999"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "customer": "Inception",
      "project": "2010"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "customer": "Interstellar",
      "project": "2014"
    }
  ]
}
const arr = data.response.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if(!acc.includes(item.customer)) {
      acc.push(item.customer);
   }
   return acc;
}, [])

console.log(arr);
```

and then you can render it like

```
render() {

   const reducedArr = this.getUniqueValues();
   return (
         <Picker
            mode="dialog"
            selectedValue={this.state.customerName}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
              this.setState({ customerName: itemValue });
              }
            }
            >
              {
                reducedArr.map((customer) => (
                <Picker.Item label={customer} value={customer} key={customer} />))
              }
            </Picker>
      )
}
```

or

```js
const data = {
  "response": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "customer": "Star Wars",
      "project": "1977"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "customer": "Star Wars",
      "project": "1985"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "customer": "The Matrix",
      "project": "1999"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "customer": "Inception",
      "project": "2010"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "customer": "Interstellar",
      "project": "2014"
    }
  ]
}
const arr = data.response.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if(!acc[item.customer]) {
      acc[item.customer] = 1;
   }
   return acc;
}, {})

console.log(arr);
```

and then you can render it like

```
render() {

   const reducedObject = this.getUniqueValues();
   return (
         <Picker
            mode="dialog"
            selectedValue={this.state.customerName}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
              this.setState({ customerName: itemValue });
              }
            }
            >
              {
                Object.keys(reducedObject).map((customer) => (
                <Picker.Item label={customer} value={customer} key={customer} />))
              }
            </Picker>
      )
}
```

or to filter out unique values, you can also make use of [`Javascript Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: +1 Side note: Using an `Object` or (if available) a `Set` as the accumulator would be more efficient so you do not have to iterate the accumulator every time to check for duplicates.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri: Can you please also add the snippet for using Set. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and check if the first occurance of a movie with a certain `customer` has the same `index` as the current `index` of the loop. This way you will only get all the unique ones.

```js
const movies = [
  {
    id: "1",
    customer: "Star Wars",
    project: "1977"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    customer: "Star Wars",
    project: "1985"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    customer: "The Matrix",
    project: "1999"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    customer: "Inception",
    project: "2010"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    customer: "Interstellar",
    project: "2014"
  }
];

const uniqueMovies = movies.filter((movie, index) => {
  return movies.findIndex(m => m.customer === movie.customer) === index;
});

console.log(uniqueMovies);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function like `uniqueArray = removeDuplicates(response, 'customer')`

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
}
```